# Intuitive idea: What is the motivation for relative homological algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modules, comodules

Basically I was wondering what is the purpous of choosing a smaller class of epis in a category?  Does it allow for the existence of "more" "projective-like" objects?

What are some applications?  For example, if I'm looking at a comodule category over a coalgebra can I force the existence of more projectives by using a relativised theory?

Comment: I don't know about comodules, but sometime projectives are not at all the "acyclic" objects you want to consider. An example is the construction of the Adams spectral sequence, where you want your acyclic objects to be retracts of $E\wedge X$, where $E$ is your ring spectrum.

Comment: Of course it allows for more projectives! A module is projective if it satisfies a certain property for each admissible epi: if there are very few admissible epis, naturally it will be easier for a module to be projectiive. For example, if you only let *split* epis be admissible, all modules become projective.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys! :) (I know that was a bad question, but sometimes I liek to make certain :D )

Comment: You might like to look at some of the work on weak factorisation systems as the connections between classes of morphisms and classes of objects is more fully explored in that area.

Comment: Sonds interesteting, may I ask for a referece.. since I'm still new in the area :D